# IDE for GPSS language

Tags: ide, simulation

GPSS stands for `General Purpose Simulation System`. And it looks like that the language is more dead than alive (I didn't find good and actual blog or web site).

I began studying this language a few weeks ago, and faced with the lack of good IDE. I have to work with GPSS World and a don't like this system.

Does anyone know if there is any IDE or IDE-like system to work with GPSS? My dream is about intellisense, good run-time debugger, etc.

P.S. Sorry, but i can't create a new tag 'gpss'.

Thanks.

Comment: Any progreess on this? Have you find someting good? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately. There are some companies in Russia, trying to do smth similar, but i didn't see the tools they made. All tips and recommendation that i received were to move from GPSS to AnyLogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It's time to answer and finally close the question. As I told to **lak-b**, there are some companies in Russia, but I didn't see their result.

However, I found the one solution - [WebGPSS](http://webgpss.com/). But I do not know if the development is in progress, or the project already died. You can figure it out by yourself. As to me, I would choose AnyLogic instead of GPSS.

Thanks.

Comment: AnyLogic is heavy tool with a lot of drag&drop stuff and feature that you don't really need we're speaking about general simulating system. GPSSw is lightweight and elegant.

Answer (score 3):

FastForward to 2016: I have used Wolverine's GPSS\H professional and student version.  There are several variations of GPSS and there are many other non-GPSS alternatives.

AGPSS has a GPSS has IDE.  A Toolbox GPSS-version exists for MATLAB (subset of commands).

GPSS's (Wolverine version) strength lies in that is computationally very efficient (lean) because it precedes Win-Tel \ DOS.  The successor to GPSS\H is Wolverine's SLX and both are considered to be at the forefront of speed and capability.  The student versions are available for download and evaluation

Answer (score 1):

I'm studing in UBA. We are using SNAKE in the Simulation course.

Comment: @mrcktz: http://materias.fi.uba.ar/7526/docs/intro_snake.pdf and http://materias.fi.uba.ar/7526/programas.html